# Best way to automate AWS EMR Creation,termination and pyspark jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, airflow, amazon-emr

I have pyspark code in S3 and I will execute them and write test cases in Pyspark and load it to the snowflake. My job runs for 1 min on a daily basis and also need log if it has failed

I am new to aws, How to trigger a new  EMR and execute pyspark job? I know we can do it through Airflow, can we do it through AWS also or any other means?

What would be better Airflow or AWS Datapipeline in terms of cost or easiness?

Thanks,
Xi

Answer (score 2):

Airflow has operators to interact with EMR. You can use `EmrCreateJobFlowOperator`, `EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator`, `EmrAddStepsOperator`, etc...
Information about the operators and how to use them can be found in this [doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/emr.html).

A skeleton DAG can be:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr import (
    EmrAddStepsOperator,
    EmrCreateJobFlowOperator,
    EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator,
)
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.emr import EmrStepSensor

with DAG(
    dag_id='emr_job_flow_manual_steps_dag',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval='0 3 * * *',
) as dag:

    # Create machine
    cluster_creator = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator()

    # Submit steps
    step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator()

    #Verify steps are completed
    step_checker = EmrStepSensor()

    #Terminate machine
    cluster_remover = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator()

    cluster_creator >> step_adder >> step_checker >> cluster_remover
```

Full example dag for manual steps is available [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/169b196d189242c4f7d26bf1fa4dd5a8b5da12d4/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags/example_emr_job_flow_manual_steps.py#L66).
Full example dag for automatic steps is available [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/169b196d189242c4f7d26bf1fa4dd5a8b5da12d4/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/example_dags/example_emr_job_flow_automatic_steps.py#L62).

Comment: When aws datapipeline can accomplish same join why do people go for airflow? Is this cheap? Or have better scheduling ? Or have better logging?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "you people" you asked about Airflow so I answered about Airflow. If you need to decide between two options I would advise you to do a POC with both and then decide. What works best for you many be different for others.